# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make the Selection and SelectionView reusable so I don't need to make multiple and can just use it with varibles. I came up with the following code:

```
import discord

from DataHandeling import data_Handeling

class Select(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self, label, emoji, description):
        options = [[discord.SelectOption(label = label[i], emoji = emoji[i], description = description[i])]for i in range(len(label))]

        # for i in range(len(label)) : discord.SelectOption(label = label[i], emoji = emoji[i], description = description[i])

        super().__init__(placeholder = "Select an option", max_values = 1, min_values = 1, options = options)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content=f'Your choice is {self.values[0]}!', ephemera1 = True)


class SelectView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout = 180, select):
        super().__init__(timeout = timeout)
        # dh = data_Handeling()
        # ldl, lde, ldd = dh.filling_variables()
        self.add_item(select)
```

From Main:

```
languageselect = Select(ldl, lde, ldd)

@bot.command(aliases = ['hilfe', 'commands'])
async def h(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Choose a language!", view = SelectView(select = languageselect))
```

Now I get the following Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 190, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dreimenschen/Desktop/Farbenvergeber/main.py", line 62, in h
    await ctx.send("Choose a language!", view = SelectView(select = languageselect))
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/context.py", line 841, in send
    return await super().send(
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1520, in send
    with handle_message_parameters(
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 187, in handle_message_parameters
    payload['components'] = view.to_components()
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 219, in to_components
    children = [item.to_component_dict() for item in group]
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    children = [item.to_component_dict() for item in group]
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ui/select.py", line 274, in to_component_dict
    return self._underlying.to_dict()
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/components.py", line 283, in to_dict
    'options': [op.to_dict() for op in self.options],
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/components.py", line 283, in <listcomp>
    'options': [op.to_dict() for op in self.options],
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 986, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/dreimenschen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 199, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

My question is, is my idea even possible and if so how can I fix my Error?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your options are lists because you have an extra pair or brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like 3nws said, I had to many brackets.

Corrected Code:

```
import discord

from DataHandeling import data_Handeling

class Select(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self, label, emoji, description):
        options = [discord.SelectOption(label = label[i], emoji = emoji[i], description = description[i])for i in range(len(label))]

        # for i in range(len(label)) : discord.SelectOption(label = label[i], emoji = emoji[i], description = description[i])

        super().__init__(placeholder = "Select an option", max_values = 1, min_values = 1, options = options)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content=f'Your choice is {self.values[0]}!', ephemera1 = True)
```

Comment: You can indent your code to make it clearer. The proof is, you haven't seen the extra brackets. Use pypi.org/project/black for example.

Comment: I have seen the extra brackets, the problem was I never had written a one-liner before and that was my first try. So that was actually my problem, but I think I understand them now.